# Any workaround to Firebase hosting not supporting audio streaming for web app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, just-audio

I have a Flutter web app that I have been deploying to Firebase hosting.

An important new feature of the web app uses audio to highlight different aspects of a key process.  To support this I am using 'just_audio' package, with small MP3 files defined as project assets.

However, I've discovered a limitation with Firebase hosting, in that it appears not to support audio streaming.  This is a killer blocker issue for me, so I was wondering if anybody had any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: since its small, and static. try convert mp3 to base64 and save it as "hard code" instead of asset. its maybe work its maybe not, worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

FYI...

I've found this Flutter package that will play audio loaded directly from assets

https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player

... and this works on Firebase hosting